# Spark: RDD as a tuple with second element as list to string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD as a tuple where its key as an integer and value as List of integers:

```
myDataRdd: RDD[(Int, List[Int])]
```

Data contains userId, the list of items the user have bought.

I want to convert this to string such that:

```
userId, Product1, Product2,...
```

I did the following:

```
val convertedRDD :RDD[String] = recs.map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2.mkString(","))
```

But when I look at the part files the structure was completely different, which was:

```
1901437510,
1471516971,
336924029,
2105754029,
1130205965,
654671035,
2096277932,
341111432,
1485082568,
1977671938,
149397938,
1655827062,
```

Comment: Are you sure `x._2` is non-empty in these cases?

Comment: Try putting quotes before and after the strings to find out.

Comment: please paste myDataRdd/recs .take(10), and have a review of sample input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
val convertedRDD = recs.map{case(int,list) => int.toString+", "+list.mkString(", ")}
```